# Spring Boot - Retrieve hidden value in controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, stripe-payments, thymeleaf

I am trying to retrieve a value (an enrollmentId) that I passed to a form in my controller.
But I don't know how to retrieve that Id from the form to the controller. I am using Stripe API and once the payment is successful, I want to setPaid= true in the entity Enrollment.

It starts here in a CheckoutController:

```
@RequestMapping("/checkout/{id}")
public String checkout(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    Enrollment enrollment = enrollmentService.load(id);
    Workshop existingWorkshop = enrollment.getWorkshop(); 
    model.addAttribute("stripePublicKey", stripePublicKey);
    model.addAttribute("enrollmentId", enrollment.getId() );
    return "checkout" ;
```

Then the enrollmentId goes to the HTML form:

```
 <form action='/charge' method='POST' id='checkout-form'>
 <input type="hidden" th:value="${enrollmentId}" name="enrollmentId"/>
```

Then I want to use that enrollmentId in the controller below (ChargeController):

```
@PostMapping("/charge")
public String charge(ChargeRequest chargeRequest, Model model) throws StripeException {
    Enrollment enrollment = enrollmentService.load(enrollmentId)
    chargeRequest.setEnrollment(enrollment);
    Charge charge = paymentsService.charge(chargeRequest);
    model.addAttribute("status", charge.getStatus());
    if (charge.getStatus() == "succeeded") {
        chargeRequest.getEnrollment().setPaid(true);
    }
    return "result";
}
```

Basically the flow is:

1. enrollmentId is in controller 1
2. enrollmentId is passed to the form in the HTML
3. enrollmentId needs to be retrieved in controller 2

I am stuck at going from step 2 to step 3. Or maybe my all way to do it is not correct.
I don't have an attribute enrollmentId in my class ChargeRequest. So I cannot use the:field to populate it. I am trying to set the relationship between the ChargeRequest and Enrollment.

```
public class ChargeRequest {
    public enum Currency {
        EUR, USD;
    }
    private String description;
    private int amount; // cents
    private Currency currency;
    private String stripeEmail;
    private String stripeToken;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Enrollment enrollment;
```

If you have any hints, I will be happy and grateful to read them. It's my first project using Spring Boot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi & Welcome! With this form, you just need to `model.addAttribute("amount", /*from somewhere*/);` and `model.addAttribute("enrollmentId", /*from somewhere*/);` (with (correct) values,) in the correct place (if succeeded!??) of controller.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot ! 
As I understand, model.addAttribute is to send info from the controller to the view.
In my case, I would need the contrary, the info to be sent from the view to the controller.

Comment: aaahhh!! :-) then, with given form, we can (in post mapping) use: `Long enrollmentId = (Long) model.getAttribute("enrollmentId");` or /additonally add: `Long @RequestParameter("enrollmentId") param` (to method params)

Comment: Great!!! That worked with RequestParam
Thank you very much @xerx593 for your help :)

Comment: Appreciate & very welcome, my friend! (sorry, too short/few details for an answer...you can probably better!:) ..and your (warm & honest) thanks *is* (more than) "reputation" to me! :-)

Comment: @Afloatz considering adding an answer with the solution and then accepting it so that others can benefit from it easily. Thanks!